# Chai: AssertionError: expected [Function] to be a function (when testing exceptions)

Tags: javascript, node.js, chai

I'm getting this error `AssertionError: expected [Function] to be a function` when I'm trying to whether a async function throws an error

```
it('has invalid password', async () => {
    const fakeData = { email: userData.email, password: 'something but not the password!.' }
    expect(async () => { await authService.authenticate(fakeData) }).to.throw(errors.UnauthenticatedError)
})
```

result:

```
AssertionError: expected [Function] to be a function
  at Assertion.assertThrows (node_modules/chai/lib/chai/core/assertions.js:1273:32)
  at Assertion.ctx.(anonymous function) (node_modules/chai/lib/chai/utils/addMethod.js:41:25)
  at doAsserterAsyncAndAddThen (node_modules/chai-as-promised/lib/chai-as-promised.js:293:29)
  at Assertion.<anonymous> (node_modules/chai-as-promised/lib/chai-as-promised.js:252:17)
  at Assertion.ctx.(anonymous function) [as throw] (node_modules/chai/lib/chai/utils/overwriteMethod.js:49:33)
  at Context.it (dist/tests/unit/auth-service.spec.js:56:20)
  at Test._mocha2.default.Test.run (node_modules/mocha-http-detect/dist/index.js:84:21)
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/chaijs/chai/issues/958

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a known issue that happens when you try to pass an async function.

To fix this issue, you can use Chai canary.

More information: https://github.com/chaijs/chai/issues/958

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea. Unfortunately, I can't update to chai@canary because chai-as-promised is locked to work with chai < 4.

Comment: @Kossgreim Try changing the peerDependencies field in the module's package.json maybe?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using async function, you can also check if it's an `AsyncFunction` in following way:

```
const myAsyncFunc = async () => {};

expect(myAsyncFunc).to.be.a('AsyncFunction');
```